# Python, search substring not in dict without for loop in one line

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, substring

```
# Get version stack ID
for key in all_version_stacks.keys():
    if "040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev" in key:  # Search for the filename with substring in Version Stack
        print('Found the Version Stack Name: ', key)
        version_stack_upl_id = all_version_stacks.get(key)
        print('Version Stack ID:             ', version_stack_upl_id)
   else:
        print('Version Stack not found')
```

My problem is that I don't want to have a result of:

```
Version Stack not found
Version Stack not found
Version Stack not found
Version Stack not found
```

I want to know if it exists in there and if yes I want to get the key.

```
version_stack_upl_id = all_version_stacks.get(key)
```

And if not I want to just get a false or one variable return. 
But as I need a for loop above I always get a print or return for every single key. I can't get my head around solving this.

I'm still learning so I hope someone of you can give me some smart advice on how to solve that.

Doesn't matter how I try it I always end up using a for loop to search as I want to use a **substring to search**, cause I don't want to search for the full key.

```
def search(target_dict, searchFor):
    for version_stack_name in target_dict:
        searchFor not in version_stack_name
```

Comment: Set a flag that you test after the loop

Comment: What do you mean by setting a flag?

Comment: It's not great practice, but you could use a try:except block with a pass in the exception, and you wouldn't need to iterate over the dictionary at all - never mind, iteration is needed, but the try:except is the way forward I think

Comment: Setting a flag - define a variable e.g. Failed=True if during the loop you get a hit, set Failed to False, then when the loop finishes you can print a message if `Failed` is still True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a flag:

```
# Get version stack ID
key_found = False
for key in all_version_stacks.keys():
    if "040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev" in key:  # Search for the filename with substring in Version Stack
        print('Found the Version Stack Name: ', key)
        version_stack_upl_id = all_version_stacks.get(key)
        print('Version Stack ID:             ', version_stack_upl_id)
        key_found = True
if not key_found:
    print("Version Stack not found")
```

Comment: `if not key found:` you are missing an underscore i.e. `if not key_found:`

Comment: Guys, you are amazing that you for all the great ways to solve this puzzle. That means a lot to me and helped me to again to learn in python.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony saw and fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a loop-less one-liner is the right solution for you; it would just make the code harder to understand.

If your issue is getting the "not found" response for every key, rather than as a whole, then you just need to move your "not found" outside the loop. That way, it will only respond once, if no matching key is found.

I've written an example function below

```
my_dict = {"AAA": 1, "BBB": 2, "CCC": 3}  # example dict

def get_key_by_substring(sub_key, store):

    for key in store.keys():  # loop through the keys
        if sub_key in key:  # if the substring is found
            return key  # return the key

    # if the substring isn't found in any key 
    return "not found" # return "not found"

print(get_key_by_substring("B", my_dict))  # returns "BBB"
print(get_key_by_substring("D", my_dict))  # returns "not found"
```

Comment: Guys, you are amazing that you for all the great ways to solve this puzzle. That means a lot to me and helped me to again to learn in python.

Answer (score 0):

This function will either return a list with all keys that match the sub-string or return false if there are no matches.

```py
def get_keys(d, sub):
    keys = []
    for k in d.keys():  # For each key
        if sub in k:  # Check if it matches the sub-string
            keys.append(k)  # Save key if it does
    if len(keys) == 0:
        return False  # If no matches are found return False
    return keys  # Else return the list of keys


d = {"firtsKey" : 1, "secondKey" : 2, "otherItem": 3}
test1 = get_keys(d, "Key")
test2 = get_keys(d, "notinkey")
print(test1)  # Outputs: ['firtsKey', 'secondKey']
print(test2)  # Outputs: False
```

A possible method of doing this in one line is:

```py
d = {"firtsKey" : 1, "secondKey" : 2, "otherItem": 3}
sub = "Key"
f = filter(lambda x: sub in x, list(d.keys()))
# Then use the results
for i in f:
   print(i) 
# Output:
# firtsKey
# secondKey
```

Comment: That's also an interesting way of approaching this and I'm glad to make my way through it. In this case, I think I won't use it as an approach as it would make my code more complicated. I'm checking the key to later get the value from that key and when using your approach I would have to check the value in a different function. Thanks for giving me another perspective.